# Invite Friends to try the app using app

Tags: android

I am developing an app, in that i want to give an option for users, to invite friends, for installing  this app. I am not getting how to do that.

If anyone have any idea please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this feature using App Invite option offered by Firebase.

[Send and Receive Firebase Invites from Your Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android)

This will help you in achieving your app sharing functionality easily.

Below are the steps that you will need to implement.

**1. Add the dependency for Firebase Invites to your app-level build.gradle file:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
```

**2. Send invitations on button click :**

```
private void onInviteClicked() {
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
        .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
        .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
        .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
        .build();
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
```

You can customize your invite further by referring the above link.